# What does 'near term order flow to be distributed across short term options' mean?

Tags: distribution

Please see the red phrase below. [Guide to Option Pinning at Options Expiration | Investing With Options](https://investingwithoptions.com/blog/2011/11/18/option-pinning-option-expiration-guide/)

> **What Have Weekly Options Done To Pinning?**
>
> That's a great question for a graduate student to cover in a thesis paper. I don't have any hard numbers, but I'll give my thoughts based on watching the market on opex this year.
>
> The introduction of weekly options into many pinning candidates has a very specific effect. Those traders looking to take positions in the short term no longer have to use the front month options. This lead to $\color{red}{\text{near term order flow to be distributed}}$  across short term options, which has led to decreased open interest on the monthly options going into expiration.
>
> So what do you think would happen here? Sure, the pinning effect should be reduced during monthly options expiration, and I think it has.
>
> But, much to my surprise, there has been **a pickup in pinning effects in the weekly options**. I don't know if this is quantifiably true, but the way that some of these weekly options trade on Friday lead me to believe that there may be a resurgence in the dark art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means market participants who trade short term option now trade several different weekly options together with the front month monthly option rather than only the front month option.